# can't add my present account to folder > Get Info > Sharing & Permissions on Macbook Pro

Tags: file-permissions

I want to access MacBook Pro OS 10.11.15 files from a Windows 7.  Can read files ok but writing causes permission problem.

At MacBook, I cannot enable Read & Write for my MacBook account.

I select my hard disk.
Open Get Info > Sharing & Permissions.
But + button is grayed out.

So then I tried going to the folder I'm working with;
open Get Info > Sharing & Perm..;
my present account is not listed;
the + is enabled so I click it;
the list shows my present account, but disabled (grayed out)